How to calculate this definite integral? or maybe, is it possible to obtain an approximate expression?
I'm currently trying to solve the following integral, and any assistance would be greatly appreciated:
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{u-2}\exp\left(-\frac{x+g(x)}{2}\right)\text{d}x
\end{equation}
where $u\geq 1$, and
\begin{equation}
g(x)=\left(a\sqrt{x} + \frac{b-c\sqrt{x}}{d+f\sqrt{x}}\right),
\end{equation}
with $a\geq0,b\geq0,c\geq0,d>0$, and $f>0$.
Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.
